# Finding a non-piecewise function that maps all $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ to $0$ and $0$ to $1$

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, integers

I am trying to devise a function that maps $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ to $0$ and maps $0$ to $1$ that is not a piecewise function.

If $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ to $0$ and maps $0$ to $1$ is not possible then a function $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ to $0$ and maps $0$ to $1$ could possibly work too.

Any help is much appreciated (I am really stuck on this one), thanks in advance for the help!

(Context: This is for a program I am trying to write without if statements)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: The difference of sets is written $A\setminus B$ (`$A\setminus B$`) not $A /B$

Comment: How about $f(x)=\text{Re}(\sqrt{1-x^2})$?

Comment: @jjagmath I can assure you this is not homework :) I am writing a code compiler for fun and trying to come up with a nonbranching way to do not logic (without an instruction).

Comment: @M.Nestor what is Re(x) here? The real component?

Comment: It's not about what you are doing, it's about how it looks like. Do you usually take the word from strangers in Internet?

Comment: There’s also the sinc function

Comment: @jjagmath well no, I understand your concerns. Let's just end this thread of commenting here :) And from now on I will try to include some work.

Comment: Glad to see you got the point. Good luck with your compiler

Comment: @yosmo78 May I ask, what programming language are you using?

Comment: Please define "piecewise function" and "non-piecewise function". I understand the difference between a continuouis function and a piecewise continuous function; a piecewise continuous function is not necessarily a continuous function. Likewise, a piecewise monotonic function may fail to be monotonic. But as far as I know, a "piecewise function" is just a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take $\left\lfloor \frac{1}{n^2+1} \right\rfloor$.

If you want to avoid using floats and the floor function,  but you are willing to use the absolute value, you can consider $\frac{1-\left|n\right|+\left|\left|n\right|-1\right|}{2}$

Comment: This is awesome! thank you!

Comment: @yosmo78 I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take $0^{n^2}$, accepting $0^0=1$.  (Strictly speaking, $|n|$ is somewhat piecewise ...)